# focus and focusout event order switching from one field to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

Let's say I have two text fields which jQuery puts on the page dynamically.
Also I have added `focus` and `focusout` event listeners on those fields.

So after elements are added on the page HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="outer">
    <input name="a" type="text" class="inner" />
    <input name="b" type="text" class="inner" />
</div>
```

jQuery code looks like this:

```
$('.outer').on('focus', '.inner', function (e) {
    // Some action
});

$('.outer').on('focusout', '.inner', function (e) {
    // Some action
});
```

So those event listeners are added on both text fields with class `inner`.

When I put first text field in focus and than I put second field in focus **immediately after**, events that will be fired are: `focus` on the first field, `focusout` also on the first field and `focus` on the second field.

My question is, in which order those events will be fired?

Which of the following is true, if any?

(Is it synchronous?)

**A:** First `focus` is fired on the **first** field, JavaScript waits for it to finish, than `focus` is fired on the **second** field, JavaScript waits for it to finish, than `focusout` is fired on the **first** field.

**B:** First `focus` is fired on the **first** field, JavaScript waits for it to finish, than `focusout` is fired on the **first** field, JavaScript waits for it to finish, than `focus` is fired on the **second** field.

(Or is it asynchronous?)

**C:** First `focus` is fired on the **first** field, JavaScript does not wait for it to finish, immediately after `focus` is fired on the **second** field, JavaScript does not wait for it to finish, immediately after `focusout` is fired on the **first** field.

**D:** First `focus` is fired on the **first** field, JavaScript does not wait for it to finish, immediately after `focusout` is fired on the **first** field, JavaScript does not wait for it to finish, immediately after `focus` is fired on the **second** field.

It's obvious that first focused element, in this case first text field, always fires first.
What confuses me is, which event is fired first after second text field is put in focus (no clicking around just straight click from the first text field to the second), `focus` (on the second field) or `focusout`(on the first field)?

And are they fired synchronously, when two event listeners listening on the two elements with same class (next event is fired only after one before it is finished)?

Or they are fired asynchronously?

I really need some inside JavaScript knowledge on this.

Comment: Did you add console.log to the events and see what order the events fire?

Comment: I will do that but I'm not sure if the results will show sync or async behaviour. My though was that it can also be browser dependent (just the opinion I'm not the expert). So I asked here for definite answer from people who know JS internals much better than I do.

Comment: the event loop itself is synchronous, but events may be triggered asynchronously (like an ajax readstate change).

Comment: https://www.quora.com/How-does-a-single-thread-handle-asynchronous-code-in-JavaScript

Comment: So after reading articles linked here and reading answers here and on the question on which mine is proclaimed duplicate, my conclusion is that B: is the answer.  I'm I right?

Answer (score 1):

When an event is triggered it is pushed to the event loop and fired in order it was triggered.

Since Javascript has a single-threaded event pool, these events are always fired one at a time, in the order in which they are triggered.

For more info see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop